# Webkit Browsers Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, wordpress, performance, browser, cross-browser

I have very strange problem with my website www.fanebi.com

The problem is that in Webkit based browsers (Google Chrome,Opera,Safari) the website loads with errors and I can see errors in console like:

**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

Sometimes I get such errors for 10,20,30 files. It can be images, css files, js files and so on. So if I get error for css or js even whole website not loads properly.

I don't see any problem with Firefox browser. It works just normal and website loads perfectly.

This problem is appearing about since 1 week. Before this, there was no such problem.

Website is based on Wordpress engine. Whenever I had such problem, I checked my mac for malware but customers also have the same issue. So, it's not only the problem of my MAC and browser.

Can anybody help me to fix that huge problem?

Comment: Any chance do you have an ad blocker enabled? If you do try disabling it and see if that works.

Comment: It works fine for me, rest aside i can assure you that it has got nothing to do with wordpress. It might be a server issue, where your website is hosted ?

Answer (score 8):

This is an error thrown by AdBlock plus or simular programs. It's nothing to worry about, you can disable the extension to remove the 'errors'.

Edit: oh, it's posted in the comments too.

Comment: I sometimes get this error when sites try to load assets over HTTPS while I'm behind a corporate firewall, so I don't think it's just AdBlock.

Comment: That's what i meant with "simular programs'. AdBlock is just a hyperactive firewall.

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem. Do you know why AdBlock treats those images as ads?

Answer (score 1):

It was a server issue, there was some limitations for my website, so, it was not working properly...

Comment: What exactly was causing it, and did you get it fixed?

Comment: There were too many http requests and sys admin restricted with some limits these requests, so i was getting errors

Answer (score 1):

it always happened when visual studio is open. Actually, this is a feature of visual studio. so in order to avoid this, you could disable it in visual studio.
more information, you can see here: http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link

[image]